# How to get max value in cypher subquery

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've read the questions about subqueries but still stuck with this use case.

I have Documents that contain one or more keywords and each document has linked user comments with a status property. I want to get just the most recent status (if it exists) returned for each document in the query. If I run a query like the following, I just get one row.

```
    MATCH (d:Document)-[:Keys]->(k:Keywords)
    WITH d,k
    OPTIONAL MATCH (d)--(c:Comments)
    ORDER BY c.created DESC LIMIT 1
    RETURN d.Title as Title, k.Word as Keyword, c.Status as Status
```

I have hundreds of documents I want to return with the latest status like:

```
Title                      Keyword  Status
War in the 19th Century    WWI      Reviewed
War in the 19th Century    Weapons  Reviewed
The Great War              WWI      Pending
World War I                WWI      <null>
```

I have tried multiple queries using WITH clause but no luck yet. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This query should do what you probably intended:

```
MATCH (d:Document)-[:Keys]->(k:Keywords)
OPTIONAL MATCH (d)--(c:Comments)
WITH d, COLLECT(k.Word) AS Keywords, c
ORDER BY c.created DESC
WHERE c IS NOT NULL
RETURN d.Title as Title, Keywords, COLLECT(c)[0] AS Status
```

Since a comment is related to a document, and not a document/keyword pair, it makes more sense to return a collection of keywords for each Title/Status pair. Your original query, if it had worked, would have returned the same Title/Status pair multiple times, each time with a different keyword.

Answer (score 1):

We've got a [knowledge base article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/limiting-match-results-per-row/) explaining how to limit results of a match per-row, that should give you a few good options.

EDIT

Here's a full example, using `apoc.cypher.run()` to perform the limited subquery.

```
MATCH (d:Document)-[:Keys]->(k:Keywords)
WITH d, COLLECT(k.Word) AS Keywords
// collect keywords first so each document on a row
CALL apoc.cypher.run('
 OPTIONAL MATCH (d)--(c:Comments)
 RETURN c
 ORDER BY c.created DESC
 LIMIT 1
', {d:d}) YIELD value
RETURN d.Title as Title, Keywords, value.c.status as Status
```

Comment: The use case requires finding the latest comment, which requires using `ORDER BY` as well as `LIMIT`. Will any of the techniques in that KB article help in this case?

Comment: Yep! Added an example for it.